# A verb to describe rising temperature in a pot

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

The lobster sits oblivious in a pot but has no idea the water is heating up and that it is actully being cooked until it is too late.

This is in context "Like lobsters cooking in an ever heatening pot, we barely noticed the change." Obviously *heatening* is not a verb, so I need one to replace it.

What verb could I use to describe the subtle rising of the temperature of the pot?

Comment: ***Imperceptibly** increasing temperature* might work, given that the lobster doesn't perceive what's happening. Of course, in the context of global climate change (which everyone thinks they *do* notice), the word of choice is usually ***inexorable***. (no-one can stop it)

Comment: Thanks, this is it in context "Like lobsters cooking in an ever heatening pot, we barely noticed the change." obviously heatening is not a verb, so need one to replace it. Any ideas?

Comment: Personally I doubt there *is* a single word for your context. But I would just say that I've not heard of this imagery being used with *lobsters*. And if I Google **lobster slowly boil to death** the first half-dozen results are actually about ***frogs*** not noticing, and I'm pretty sure it's really true with frogs (I feel like I've known that version all my life). I have my doubts that lobsters could be that insensitive, but given the frogs version is so well-known I think I'd just rephrase to *Like **frogs being slowly boiled alive**, we barely noticed the change*.

Comment: There is an idiom/fable about frogs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boiling_frog), even though  it's false. I suspect there isn't a verb that captures the idiom, or it would have taken over.

Comment: I wonder if what you're actually looking for is an adverb? // *Heating* not *heatening*, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

"Like lobsters in water **edging** toward boiling, we didn't noticed the subtle change"

> **edge**
>   verb
>   **2** [with adverbial of direction] Move or cause to move gradually or furtively in a particular direction.
>   [no object] ‘she tried to edge away from him’
>   [with object] ‘Hazel quietly edged him away from the others’
>   [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/edge)

Comment: *Creeping* would be something similar in terms of a single verb.

Comment: @JasonBassford and matt "creeping" is nice. It has a sneaky feeling to it.

Comment: @DavidD Feel free to add it to your answer as an alternative. You don't have to provide just *one* word. (And it's similar enough.)

Comment: I've gone for this "Like lobsters in a pot creeping towards boiling, we barely noticed.  Until it was too late." Thanks again! What a helpful website!